# Code does not work in android 2.1

Tags: android, contacts

I'm working on an android application thats dealing with contact.

I have used the following code in android 1.6 and it works fine.

```
public static Uri getProfilepicture(Activity activity, String address)
{
    Uri personUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, address);
    Cursor phoneCursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(personUri,PHONE_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    if (phoneCursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        int indexPersonId = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(Phones.PERSON_ID);
        long personId = phoneCursor.getLong(indexPersonId);
        phoneCursor.close();

        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, personId);
        return uri;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and getting photo in bitmap like

```
Bitmap bm =  People.loadContactPhoto(activity,getProfilepicture(activity, ConNum, R.drawable.artist, null);
```

Can any one suggest code for android 2.1 please?

Comment: People 'This class is deprecated.
see ContactsContract'

Comment: thanks for comment selvin. i know i have to use ContactsContract. in api 2.1 i m trying with that but do not get output. if you have any working example of that, please provide me.

Comment: @milind I think [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-using-the-contact-picker/) is the rare example using ContactsContract....You might have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Friends to trying to help me. i have solve the problem by following code.

```
public static Bitmap getContactPhoto(Activity activity,int contactId) 
{
    Bitmap photo = null;

    final String[] projection = new String[] {
            Contacts.PHOTO_ID                       // the id of the column in the data table for the image
    };

    final Cursor contact = activity.managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,projection,Contacts._ID + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)},null);

    if(contact.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        final String photoId = contact.getString(
                contact.getColumnIndex(Contacts.PHOTO_ID));
        if(photoId != null) 
        {
            photo = queryContactBitmap(activity,photoId);
        } 
        else 
        {
            photo = null;
        }
        contact.close();

    }
    contact.close();
    return photo;
}


private static Bitmap queryContactBitmap(Activity activity,String photoId) 
{
    final Cursor photo = activity.managedQuery(Data.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {Photo.PHOTO},Data._ID + "=?",new String[]{photoId},null);

    final Bitmap photoBitmap;
    if(photo.moveToFirst()) 
    {
        byte[] photoBlob = photo.getBlob(
                photo.getColumnIndex(Photo.PHOTO));
        photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                photoBlob, 0, photoBlob.length);
    } 
    else 
    {
        photoBitmap = null;
    }
    photo.close();
    return photoBitmap;
}
```

in that just pass the activity object and contactId. and store it into bitmam.